# Remove certain values from an array generated by get_the_category()

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to print out some categories of a Wordpress post. To archieve this, I use the `get_the_category();` function, which I set equal to a new variable.

Before the categories get echoed, I want to remove two of them ("News" and "Ranking") and rename the categories "Japan" and "English" into "Japan News" and "English News". But when I run my code it does not the categories, as all of them were printed out.

Here is the current code:

```
$categories = get_the_category();

$del_val1 = 'News';
$del_val2 = 'Ranking';

 if(($key = array_search($del_val1, $categories)) !== false) {
        unset($categories[$key]);
    }
 if(($key = array_search($del_val2, $categories)) !== false) {
            unset($categories[$key]);
        }

echo $categories->cat_name;
```

And this is the content of the array only as an example:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#3051 (17) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    &int(30)
    ["name"]=>
    &string(11) "Deutschland"
    ["slug"]=>
    &string(11) "deutschland"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(30)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(8) "category"
    ["description"]=>
    &string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    &int(2)
    ["count"]=>
    &int(3)
    ["object_id"]=>
    int(527)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    &int(30)
    ["category_count"]=>
    &int(3)
    ["category_description"]=>
    &string(0) ""
    ["cat_name"]=>
    &string(11) "Deutschland"
    ["category_nicename"]=>
    &string(11) "deutschland"
    ["category_parent"]=>
    &int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#3068 (17) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    &int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    &string(4) "News"
    ["slug"]=>
    &string(4) "news"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(8) "category"
    ["description"]=>
    &string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    &int(0)
    ["count"]=>
    &int(6)
    ["object_id"]=>
    int(527)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    &int(2)
    ["category_count"]=>
    &int(6)
    ["category_description"]=>
    &string(0) ""
    ["cat_name"]=>
    &string(4) "News"
    ["category_nicename"]=>
    &string(4) "news"
    ["category_parent"]=>
    &int(0)
  }
}
```

Comment: corrected.. my mistake. But the error is still happening

Comment: what does `$categories` contain anyway? `var_dump($categories)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($categories as $key=>$cat)
{
    if (in_array($cat->cat_name, array($del_val1, $del_val2))) {
        unset($categories [$key]);
    }
}
```

`array_search` is no good because it searches on array values, but the array is an array of objects and the category name is an object property.